# How to update list base on array item in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have One List where we have some data and flags, I need to update those flags based on another array that contains Ids, if any id is not found in the List then add this Id in list with some default values.
My list and arrays are :

```
 var objBaseList =[{Id :1,:Value:"Name1",Status:false,IsDeleted:false},
                              {Id :2,:Value:"Name2",Status:false,IsDeleted:false},
                              {Id :3,:Value:"Name3",Status:false,IsDeleted:false},
                              {Id :4,:Value:"Name4",Status:false,IsDeleted:false},
                              {Id :5,:Value:"Name5",Status:false,IsDeleted:false},
                              {Id :6,:Value:"Name6",Status:false,IsDeleted:false},
                              {Id :7,:Value:"Name7",Status:false,IsDeleted:false},
                              {Id :8,:Value:"Name8",Status:false,IsDeleted:false},
                              {Id :9,:Value:"Name9",Status:false,IsDeleted:false},
                             ]
                             
 var listIds = [2,6,7];
```

I need to do it in Jquery. Any Idea what approach should i follow

Comment: What you tried by your self? Some code or anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is your code to find a related value of your object

```js
var objBaseList =[{Id :1,Value:"Name1",Status:false,IsDeleted:false},
                              {Id :2,Value:"Name2",Status:false,IsDeleted:false},
                              {Id :3,Value:"Name3",Status:false,IsDeleted:false},
                              {Id :4,Value:"Name4",Status:false,IsDeleted:false},
                              {Id :5,Value:"Name5",Status:false,IsDeleted:false},
                              {Id :6,Value:"Name6",Status:false,IsDeleted:false},
                              {Id :7,Value:"Name7",Status:false,IsDeleted:false},
                              {Id :8,Value:"Name8",Status:false,IsDeleted:false},
                              {Id :9,Value:"Name9",Status:false,IsDeleted:false},
                             ]
                             
 var listIds = [2,6,7];
for(var i=0; i<listIds.length; i++) 
{
  if (objBaseList.findIndex(item => item.Id == listIds[i]) == -1) {
  console.log('Not found');

} else {
  console.log('Found :'+listIds[i])
}
}
```

now based on condition you can set the value as per your requirements.

Comment: worked like charm, I have changed the condition according to situation....